# Characters: [ ] and { } displaying incorrectly in native terminal

Tags: terminal, iterm

I have a problem I am unsure how to solve. These characters: [ ] and { } display incorrectly in the native terminal app on Mac. I have isolated it to that app by testing with iTerm, which displays the characters correctly. Please see screenshots, the first is the file in iTerm, the second the file in Mac Terminal. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image: iTerm]

[image: Mac Termional]

Comment: Would you please post your locale?

Comment: Here is my locale:LANG="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_CTYPE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=

Comment: I've also just noticed, this problem does not occur when running irssi. I find this really weird.

Comment: Update: a restart fixed this. I don't know why I didn't think of trying that. Weird bug.